# how to call a VF page from another VF page using button?

Tags: visualforce, controller

This is VF page:
Here I need to save 1 account record as well call another VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"  extensions="displayRecordsInSF1Extension1" showHeader="false">
 <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock title="Create Account">          
          <div id="detail-example">                   
                Account Name<br></br><apex:inputField  value="{!Account.Name}"/>                           
                Phone<br></br><apex:inputField  value="{!Account.Phone}" /><br></br>
                Website<br></br><apex:inputField   value="{!Account.Website}" /><br></br>
                Fax<br></br><apex:inputField value="{!Account.Fax}" /> 
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" /> 
                </apex:pageBlockButtons> 


          </div> 
          </apex:pageBlock>                  
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This is Controller Extension:

```
public class displayRecordsInSF1Extension1
{

    public Account a {get; set;}
    public displayRecordsInSF1Extension1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {

    }   
    public PageReference save()
    {             
       PageReference reRend = page.accountRecordsVf2;           
       return reRend;
    }
}
```

Here I am able to call another VF page but How To save the record.
please help me out

Comment: Before the `return reRend;` do whatever you want to do; Before this you can insert record in db can update or can delete or can undelete;

Comment: But how to save record through this VF page at same time?

Comment: You can use standard methods from the standard controller. => controller.save() will save your record.

Comment: It's showing this error:'Maximum stack depth reached: 1001 '

Comment: @sivanee - Maximum stack depth reached: 1001 will occur only on endless loop. Do check debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use the custom variable of Account let say,

```
Account a;
```

and use this variable to show the account fields on vf page then you can just use

```
insert a;
```

If you don't want to use another variable then you can try to use oncomplete attribute of commanbutton and call another PageReference action method to navigate to a new page.

Comment: can u please send the code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish it is :

```
Account a;

public PageReference saveAccount(){
     insert a;
     PageReference page  = page.accountRecordsVf2; 
     return page;
}
//ON VF
use {!a.name} and so.. and
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveAccount}" value="Save"/>
```